# TABLESPACE creation error

Tags: oracle, tablespaces, datafile

I have an error "ORA-01537" when I create a tablespace.

```
create tablespace "VOLUMT" datafile 'VOLUMT.dbf' size 250M autoextend on;
```

Then, it shows like following.

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-01537: cannot add file 'VOLUMT.dbf' - file
>   already part of database

I just change the tablespace name of VOLUMT to TEST01, and it works..

> Tablespace created.

So, I get into the directory of db and searched the related tablespace..

```
${HOME}/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12
```

However, I can't find any.. Coudl you help me to solve this problem? Also I need to use "VOLUMT" for tablespace creation.. not TEST01..

-- Additional --

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME from DBA_DATA_FILES;

TABLESPACE
----------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
USERS
TEST01
```

I can see TEST01 Tablespace, but I can't find any datafiles in the directory.
Also I can't find any VOLLMT tablespace in it..

Thank you.

Comment: Apparently you already have a **file** with that name. What is the output of `select TABLESPACE_NAME, file_name from DBA_DATA_FILES;`?

Comment: Output is only TABLESPACE
----------
FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYSTEM
/home/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12/ID/system01.dbf

SYSAUX
/home/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12/ID/sysaux01.dbf

USERS
/home/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12/ID/ID_user01.dbf

Comment: There is no such a "VOLUMT"..

Comment: @owcred601 Please edit your post and add the output of the query. Format the output as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your issue can be:

create the tablespace named as `VOLUMT` ,  but for the file name change it a bit like `VOLUMT1.dbf` or else specify a different directory path to save the file in.

```
create tablespace "VOLUMT" datafile 'VOLUMT1.dbf' size 250M autoextend on;
```

please check and tell me if it worked fine.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! WOW! WHAT WAS THE PROBLEM??? Is $ORACLE_HOME/db/oradata/SID/ the correct directory that dbf is created?

Comment: It should be the correct directory, if other data files of the same database are stored there then definitely its the correct path

Comment: The problem was that there is a data file from another database with the same name, they are all stored in the same directory. simply on OS level, you cannot have 2 files with same name.

Comment: Now I can't find the "VOLUMT.dbf" file on the above directory. How can I check where the file is. Because, once I create a tablespace and remove it, then I can't create it again. ORACLE says the file already exists. I can't understand what it happens.

Comment: SELECT FILE_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME LIKE 'VOLUMT';

Comment: note that the data file name is VOLUMT1.dbf

Comment: Learn to specify the full path for your datafiles.  Don't put datafiles belonging to different databases in the same directory.

Comment: Ah! I found them, and even though I create another DB, ORACLE puts the dbf files in the same directory! ... for a sec.. don't put? it sounds there is a configuration that I can put the dbfs in the different directory.

Comment: If you want to store the files in a different path, you only have to specify the full path before the file name like this:    create tablespace "VOLUMT" datafile '/home/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12/ID/MyDatabase/VOLUMT1.dbf' size 250M autoextend on;

Comment: In regards to the existing data files,you can move them into another directory but needs some workaround.

Comment: Got it.. You. are. real. my hero.. Thank you Thank you so much.. really.

Comment: @owcred601 you're most welcome, vote up if you are satisfied with my solution

Comment: Sure I have to!! :)

Answer (score 1):

all the guys..

First of all, really appreciate to you all for replying...

When I input the follwing

```
select   file_name,
         file_id,
         tablespace_name,
         status,online_status 
from     dba_data_files 
order by tablespace_name;
```

The output is

```
FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   FILE_ID TABLESPACE STATUS    ONLINE_
---------- ---------- --------- -------
/home/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12/ID/sysaux01.dbf
    28 SYSAUX     AVAILABLE ONLINE

/home/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12/ID/system01.dbf
    27 SYSTEM     AVAILABLE SYSTEM

/home/oracle/db/oradata/ORAC12/ID/ID_user01.dbf
    29 USERS      AVAILABLE ONLINE
```

There is no such as "VOLUMT" tablespace. When I re-try to create a "TEST01" tablespace, eventhough it's already deleted, it shows 'the file exists already'..

When I get into the directory, there are other SID's as well. And, one of them has "VOLUMT". However, they are different "SID" so they can have same name of tablespace, isn't it?

Comment: When you delete the tablespace, the data file may still exist on OS level (although this is a rare case, but look for the file in the path)

Comment: I can't find any dbf file such as TEST**.. Could you let me know the exact oracle directory path that all the dbf files are created??

Comment: Don't mix up between file name and tablespace name, you can have same tablespace name on different SID's, but you cannot have same file name even if they were on different databases

Comment: Yes, there is no same name of  directory on the SID. However, there is a VOLUMT tablespace in the one of the directory. What do you call the directory? DB?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get indicates that there is an existing data file with the same name specified `VOLUMT.dbf`.

Check if there is an existing file with the same name.

```
SELECT FILE_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE LOWER(FILE_NAME) LIKE '%volumt.dbf';
```

---

To find the data file path for **TEST01** you can easily query it through the following statement

```
SELECT FILE_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME LIKE 'TEST01';
```

Comment: Yes, as you said, I can see it. However, in the case of VOLUMT, it's not.. The result is only 'no rows selected'..

Answer (score 0):

You are only looking at the tablespaces and not at the database files. 
Try querying the [`dba_data_files`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3083.htm#REFRN23049) Data Dictionary View.

Here an example command:

```
set pages 50
set lines 230
column file_name format a60

select file_name, file_id, tablespace_name, status,online_status 
from dba_data_files order by tablespace_name;
```

This should list all the database files and show you to which tablespace they belong.

---

*In response to your comment*:

You might have to switch the SID and run the query for each SID in order to determine which database files names have already been used.

You can't have the same database file (name) for a different SID and a different tablespace in the same directory.

### Possible Solutions

1. You will either have to delete the database file `VOLUMT.dbf` from the tablespace it is currently attached to, to be able to re-create the tablespace `VOLUMT` with the `VOLUMT.dbf database file.
2. You will have to create the tablespace `VOLUMT`using the database file `VOLUMT.dbf` in a different directory.

Your issue isn't the tablespace `VOLUMT`, but the database file `VOLUMT.dbf` that already exists for a different SID and a different tablespace.

Comment: Checked, but I can't find any kind of "VOLUMT" tablespace in my oracle directory... Except for inside of anther SID.

Comment: I have edited my answer and responded to your feedback.

Answer (score -4):

**delete the offending tablespace and it's contents**. use

```
DROP TABLESPACE 'the tablespace name' INCLUDING CONTENTS;
```

for your case;

```
DROP TABLESPACE VOLUMT INCLUDING CONTENTS;
```

Comment: I seriously doubt the asker wants to drop the tablespace and lose all their data!